# Reading the data from selected RadioButton in HTML table using repetaer

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working with HTML table. I am adding the data into rows using Repeater Item. I am reading some data from database. My service is returning correct data. But the UI side, when I select one row in the UI(HTMl table), radio button checked event is not triggering. I am using HTMLInputRadioButton in my repeater. I am missing some thing and I am also not sure where should call my HTMLInputRadioButton object reference. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
{
  Samplerow = ((Sample)e.Item.DataItem);
  HtmlInputRadioButton Radio1 = e.Item.FindControl("rowSelector1") as HtmlInputRadioButton;
  Literal pID = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("pID");
  pId.text=String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row.Sub_ID) ? "" : row.Sub_ID.ToString();

  Literal pName = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("pName");
  String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row.Sub_Name) ? "" : row.Sub_Name.ToString();
  Literal ValueID = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("ValueID");
  ValueID.Text = row.Sub_ID.ToString();
}
```

Comment: what event is this code within? Is this for creating content, or reacting to some event in the Repeater? There's nothing in here which appears to relate to radio buttons being checked or not.

Comment: this is Repeater ItemdataBound event.

Comment: SubAccountRepeater.DataSource = Subs;
SubAccountRepeater.DataBind();

Comment: It is for adding the data to HTML Table. In my UI table I have radio buttons for each row. After selecting the row it should redirect to next page and dispaly cell data into labels.

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Comment: @ADyson Can you please help me about UI side like what should I write in ItemTemplate in aspx page

Comment: you said "radio button checked event is not triggering". Where are you defining this event? It's not (and nor should it be, IMO) in the code you've posted.